# how to add a filter webpart using visual studio in sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have created a sitepage in sharepoint designer and its working fine with the filter webparts. But, I need to deploy the same page using visual studio. It was published successfully to the sitepages folder, but the page is not opening. Error `[No relevant source lines]` is showing. When I remove the filter webpart, the error is gone. Any idea about this error ?

EDIT

`<%@ Register TagPrefix="SPSWC" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.Office.Server.FilterControls, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>` This reference is not loaded even if its in the aspx page. How can I forcefully load that ?